# What is the colon in kubectl run command

Tags: kubernetes

Recently when I am reading [Kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/connect-applications-service/#accessing-the-service), I met the command like below:

> kubectl run curl --image=radial/busyboxplus:curl -i --tty

I know the kubectl run syntax is like the part before the colon, however I am not sure what is colon usage in the kubectl run, it is not mentioned in kubectl run syntax[2](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#run), which is:

```
$ kubectl run NAME --image=image [--env="key=value"] [--port=port] [--dry-run=server|client] [--overrides=inline-json] [--command] -- [COMMAND] [args...]
```

And also I am not sure what is the usage of

> curl -i --tty

from documentation, -i stands for "stdin", but why need --tty ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am not sure what is colon usage in the kubectl run

It's the docker container's "tag", which identifies which version of [radial/busyboxplus](https://hub.docker.com/r/radial/busyboxplus/tags?page=1&ordering=last_updated) you wish for kubernetes to run

> from documentation, -i stands for "stdin", but why need --tty ?

That is only required if the process expects to interact with a virtual terminal; you are free to omit it, and only add it back in if the container emits an error. The same is true for the `-i` -- or actually, in this case, it is *more likely* that you can omit the `-i` than `--tty` unless you are expecting to read the curl payload from your local machine

Comment: Thank you @mdaniel, that makes sense, as follow up, I wonder, in kubectl run document(https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#run) , as it said "tty Allocated a TTY for each container in the pod.". What is "TTY" here in the words "Allocate a TTY" ? From my case does it mean connecting the host stdin to a container's stdin, is my understanding correct ?

Comment: a little web searching is an expected prerequisite for both SO and _for sure_ when interacting with kubernetes: [TeleTYpewriter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teleprinter#Teleprinters_in_computing)

Comment: I think my understanding regarding --tty parameter is correct, it connects host stdin to container's stdin

Answer (score 2):

+1 to [mdaniel's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/225016/mdaniel) answer however let me also add a few words to what was already said.

First of all I must say that you're grouping the expressions in quite a strange way  And it's not about `kubectl` command syntax but general convention applied to all **Unix/Linux** commands. Just take a look at it again:

```
kubectl run curl --image=radial/busyboxplus:curl -i --tty
```

There are no spaces between `:` and preceding/proceeding part so your natural interpretation should be rather that the following fragment:

```
--image=radial/busyboxplus:curl
```

is a separated/extracted part of the whole command. It's a flag `--image` belonging to `kubectl run` command specification with its value which happens to be `radial/busyboxplus:curl`. And this value cannot be part of kubectl specification as here you put simply the name of the docker image so your searching should go naturally to **docker images naming convention** rather looking for the meaning of `:` in context of `kubectl` command.

And this is nothing unusual. As [mdaniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/225016/mdaniel) already stated in his answer, after `:` you specify **docker image tag**. Compare it with [this example](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#creating-a-deployment) where `nginx:1.14.2` is used. Using only `nginx` means `nginx:latest` as by default the latest tag is used but if we want a specific image version, we can provide it as tag, in this case `1.14.2` after the `:`.

In your example it's an image named `radial/busyboxplus` and tagged `curl`. In other words `curl` is the specific version of the `radial/busyboxplus` image.

As to:

> curl -i --tty

such grouping of the expression is completely wrong. You posted it as if there was something like:

```
--image=radial/busyboxplus:"curl -i --tty"
```

in your command. ❗ **But there aren't any quotes there.**

So coming back again to Unix command convention, you should never group parts of the expression this way. Let's take a look again at your command:

```
kubectl run curl --image=radial/busyboxplus:curl -i --tty
```

There are **meaningful spaces** in between the individual parts of the command so both `-i` and `--tty` are flags of `kubectl run` command, the same as `--image` and are part of its specification.

To avoid any confusion you can re-arrange it a bit and it could look as well like this:

```
kubectl run curl -i --tty --image=radial/busyboxplus:curl
```

To check the meaning and usage of both flags you just need to run:

```
kubectl run --help
```

(the meaning and justification for use of `-i` and `--tty` has already been well expalained by [mdaniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/225016/mdaniel).)

Comment: Hi Mario, thank you so much for detailed explanation, it is a tag only, I am shameful.